# sum of Counted number of occurance cases in a given month using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

THE OUTPUT SHOULD BE LIKE THIS

```
S/NO.   MONTH   | CIVIL |CRIMINAL | TOTAL

1   JANUARY 
2   FEBRUARY    
3   MARCH   
4   APRIL
5   MAY     
6   JUNE    
7   JULY    
8   AUGUST  
9   SEPTEMBER   
10  OCTOBER 
11  NOVEMBER    
12  DECEMBER    
    GRAND TOTAL


SELECT JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH , (SELECT COUNT(JUD_CASE_CATEGORY) FROM[hospitaldb].[dbo].[CF_CASE_REGISTER] WHERE JUD_CASE_CATEGORY ='CIVIL CASES' AND JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH LIKE '%BER%') as CIVIL,(SELECT COUNT(JUD_CASE_CATEGORY) FROM[hospitaldb].[dbo].[CF_CASE_REGISTER] WHERE JUD_CASE_CATEGORY ='CRIMIMAL CASES'AND JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH LIKE '%BER%') as CRIMINAL
FROM [hospitaldb].[dbo].[CF_CASE_REGISTER]
GROUP BY JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH
Union all
select 'SUM' JUD_CASE_CATEGORY, COUNT(JUD_CASE_CATEGORY)
from [hospitaldb].[dbo].[CF_CASE_REGISTER]
```

I want to display month, case category(civil and criminal) and total of all case category registered on a given month. to have a sum and a count of all case categories in a given month .

Comment: Good luck! By the way, if you want help with this, you need to give a lot more information. See [ask]

Comment: Results examples? current code?

Comment: Your question does not give us the required info to help. I want a burrito for lunch, but me telling you that doesn't mean you will be able to assist me achieve my goal.

Comment: SELECT JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH ,(SELECT COUNT(JUD_CASE_CATEGORY) FROM[hospitaldb].[dbo].[CF_CASE_REGISTER] WHERE JUD_CASE_CATEGORY ='CIVIL CASES' AND JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH LIKE '%BER%') as CIVIL,(SELECT COUNT(JUD_CASE_CATEGORY) FROM[hospitaldb].[dbo].[CF_CASE_REGISTER] WHERE JUD_CASE_CATEGORY ='CRIMIMAL CASES'AND JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH LIKE '%BER%') as CRIMINAL FROM [hospitaldb].[dbo].[CF_CASE_REGISTER] 
GROUP BY JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH Union all
select 'SUM' JUD_CASE_CATEGORY, COUNT(JUD_CASE_CATEGORY)
from [hospitaldb].[dbo].[CF_CASE_REGISTER]

Comment: I want to display month, case category(civil and criminal) and total of all case category registered on a given month. to have a sum and a count of all case categories in a given month

Comment: @Chrispin If you want to add information, please edit your question, rather than leaving comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH , 
  SUM(CASE WHEN JUD_CASE_CATEGORY = 'CIVIL CASES'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'CIVIL CASES',
  SUM(CASE WHEN JUD_CASE_CATEGORY = 'CRIMIMAL CASES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'CRIMIMAL CASES',
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM [hospitaldb].[dbo].[CF_CASE_REGISTER]
WHERE JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH LIKE '%BER%'
GROUP BY JUD_CASE_FILED_MONTH
```